# Mips multiplication of two numbers function

Tags: assembly, mips

I would like to know why i am getting a decimal number as the answer. For example if i enter 2 and 2 the answer should be 4 but the output is 0.04

```
.data
msg1: .asciiz "Please enter a number i "

msg2:.asciiz "Please enter a number j "

.text

.globl main

main:

la $a0,msg1 #print message

li $v0,4

syscall

li $v0,5

syscall

move $a1,$v0 #i

la $a0,msg2 #print message

li $v0,5

syscall

move $a2,$v0 #j

jal cal

addi $a0,$a0,0

li $v0,1 #print integer in reg a0

syscall

li $v0,10

syscall

cal:

mult $a1,$a2

mfhi $a0

syscall

jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `syscall` on the next-to-last line, with no operation code specified - it could do basically ANYTHING, depending on what happened to be in $v0 at that point.  With your test inputs of 2 and 2, $v0 has a 2 in it, which is the "print float" operation.  So, your program printed an arbitrary, meaningless float value (which happened to be `0.0`), followed by the correct result of `4`.